# Add keywords to an app file

Tags: finder, applications, spotlight, plist

Some built-in Mac apps have keywords attached to them, to allow for easier searching in Spotlight:

[image: The Keywords section in the Get Info window for Music.app]

How would I add these keywords to a third-party app? For example, adding the keyword "Chat" to a chat app that I downloaded, so that when I type "chat" in Spotlight, it shows that app.

Comment: As mentioned below, "keywords" are based on entries in an application's main **Info.plist** and localized **InfoPlist.strings** files - changing those in any given application will most likely break the code seal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on my experience, not with *keywords*, but with *tags*.

I suggest that **keywords** are not what you should be trying to use. This is because it is not easy to add keywords to existing files.

For files and applications (which are a bundle of files) keywords are included *in* the file when the file is created of modified. In other words they are part of the file.

Keywords are also used for photos inside a Photos library. These keywords are held in a database.

Both types of keywords are extracted from the file or database by the Spotlight indexing processes and are, as you know, available for Spotlight and Finder searches.

You will have more success using **tags**. Tags are not part of a files content, rather they are file system metadata.  Since they are in the file system, tags can be added to any kind of file without modifying the file content. More precisely, tags are stored as *extended attributes* associated with the file.

Tags are most easily added in Finder using the Get Info window or by right-click and choosing Tags...

There are also command line apps and GUI apps (e.g. Leap) which you can install to assist tagging.  But you don't need these to get started with tags.

In Spotlight or Finder, you can search using `tag:word` syntax where word is your chosen tag-word.

Warning: It is very easy to get carried away with tags, freely creating tags every time you see a file. Very soon you forget the tags you have used and they rapidly become useless for searching.

Even with a relatively small subset of your files (e.g. just applications) it is easy to get in a mess. As a trivial example, did you tag an app with *sound* or *audio*? Can you remember next time you install another related app.

I have found it essential to stick to a small set of tags and which will be easily remembered.  I use about 40 tags for applications, which is really too big but just manageable.  And I have saved searches for each of those tags.

Since I use tags for other types of files, I try to distinguish my 'application' tags from others by starting my application tags with the character @. So a Spotlight search example would be:

[image: tag search]

Another warning: You can't add tags to apps which are part of macOS - e.g. Music.  This is because they are in the signed system volume of recent macOS versions. The only solution I have found for this is to create aliases for these apps.  I then keep these aliases in a subfolder of `/Applications`.

I am somewhat of an app-junkie, so it is essential to have an easy way of finding my apps. Strictly controlled tagging is my solution.

Comment: If you just typed `@audio` or whatever the tag name (without the `tag:`) is into Spotlight, this wouldn't work, right?

Comment: @ma1234 It does need the `tag:`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to find an app when searching with an arbitrary keyword, you can simply add such keywords to the **comments** field.

For example, if you want to be able to find Firefox when typing "browser" in Spotlight, right-click on the Firefox app, select *Get info*, enter "browser" in the comments field, and close the window:

[image: comments field in file info]

Then, right after that, Spotlight will find Firefox when you search for "browser":

[image: Spotlight finds Firefox searching for browser]

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. I added a keyword to an app, but the app still doesn't show up when I search for the keyword.

Comment: @ma1234 It may take a little time until Spotlight has re-indexed the app. Sometimes it works immediately, sometimes it takes a few minutes. Other than that, I wouldn't know. Just verified that it still works in Ventura.

Comment: Weird, when I added the keyword, I forgot about it and tried it a week later, still didn't work. But it's fine, I just renamed the app file.

Comment: @ma1234 I just seemed to have this issue, but then I realized a tiny "show more" on top right of the app search results. When I clicked on it, my app was there. It's a shame that Apple has removed the option to configure the Spotlight search results.